# Android: layout_weight not working when it is set programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem when I set the `TableRow` `layout_weight` programmatically. 
Following code is the `TableLayout` inflated in `table_body` element:

```
<TableLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:weightSum="1">
<TableLayout>
```

I want to display only 10 rows in `TableLayout`.. and to do this i add `TableRow` elements **programmatically** using this is the code:

```
while(i<10){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().
        inflate(R.layout.body_row, table_body, false);

    TableRow.LayoutParams row_params = 
        new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.1f);

    table_body.addView(row, row_params);

    i++;
}
```

body_row.xml has this code:

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView 
        android:text="row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</TableRow>
```

With this code `TableLayout` is not divided in 10 equal space (as I'd want) but rows only wrap their content with the result of blank space between the end of last row and the end of the TableLayout.. What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!!

Comment: If you inflated the `body_row` layout file with `table_body` as the parent why did you set the `LayoutParams` as `TableRow.LayoutParams` instead of `TableLayout.LayoutParams`? Either use `getLayoutParams()` on the row `TableRow` and modify it or use `TableLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thank u!! It works!!! But i haven't understood why i have to set the weight of `TableRow` in `TableLayout.LayoutParams`  and not in `TableRow.LayoutParams`? In xml layout_weight is set in `<TableRow>` attribute..

Comment: A child `View` always gets its `LayoutParams` from its parent so the `TableRow` needs the `TableLayout.LayoutParams`(as the `TableLayout` is its parent). The `layout_weight` is set on the `TableRow` widget but the value it's stored in the `LayoutParams` that it gets from the parent.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you.. Hope to remember for next time..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the weight mechanism work you need to use the proper `LayoutParams` for your inflated `TableRow` widgets. As the parent of `TableRow` is a `TableLayout` then you need to use the `TableLayout.LayoutParams`:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams row_params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.1f);
table_body.addView(row, row_params);
```